# Arduino UNO & Modem Sim800L Can't write setup commands to send data to server

Tags: tcp, arduino, gsm, sim800, sim800l

I am using arduino UNO board, with modem sim800l. I want use it to send data to server, but the problem is that I can't write the setup commands.

What am I doing wrong? Are not this the right commands to use for sim800l?
I've tried with different commands and the output is the same.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//Create software serial object to communicate with SIM800L
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3, 2); //SIM800L Tx & Rx is connected to Arduino #3 & #2

void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM800L
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
  delay(100);
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+CMEE=2"); // Error mode 
  delay(100);
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, i t will back to OK
  delay(100);
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CFUN=1"); //Level "full functionality" 
  delay(100);
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CGATT?"); //attach or detach from GPRS service 
  delay(100);
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CSTT=\"net\",\"\",\"\""); //AT+CSTT AT command sets up the apn, user name and password for the PDP context.
  delay(2000);
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CSTT?"); //AT+CSTT show apn
  delay(2000);
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIICR"); //  Brings up wireless connection
  delay(2000);
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIFSR"); //  Get local IP address if connected
  delay(2000);
  updateSerial();
}
```

Here is the output from the console of Arduino IDE:

```
Initializing... 
AT+CHEE=2 
OK 
AT 
OK 
AT+CFUN=1 
OK 
AT+CGAIT? 
+CGATT: 1 
OK 
AT+CSTT="net","","" 
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed 
AT+CSTT? 
+CSTT: "CMNET","","" 

OK 
AT+CIICR 
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed 
AT+CIFSR 
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have my sympathies, it took me weeks to get my Arduino talking to the net. I think your problem is happening on the line containing "CSTT", which I don't think SIM800L recognises.

Try the below setup instead, with "SAPBR" in its place:

```
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7, 8); // working here with Arduino ports 7 and 8
void setup() {
  gprsSerial.begin(19200);
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.println("connect to GPRS");
  gprsSerial.println("AT");
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CREG?");  
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CSQ ");
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"" + String(APN) + "\"");
  delay(300);
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"USER\",\"" + String(USER) + "\"");
  delay(300);
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"PWD\",\"" + String(PWD) + "\"");
  delay(1000);
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
}
```

Your run loop:

```
void loop(){
// Do your stuff
}
```

And your toSerial function:

```
void toSerial()
{
  delay(200);
  if(gprsSerial.available()>0){
    textMessage = gprsSerial.readString();
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(textMessage);    
  }
}
```

Your call server function should be like this:

```
void callServer() {
  Serial.println("Calling server");
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CCLK?");
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http:[YOURURL]") // NOTE: NOT HTTPS!
  delay(1000);
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
  delay(3000);
  toSerial();
  gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD");
  delay(3000);
  toSerial();
}
```

Comment: The bearer in that case is probably open, in which case A) it doesn't matter - it won't break anything and B) you can close the bearer before that if you really want! "gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");" and then open it again, : "gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");" Basically I think you can ignore that error and continue with the connection process.

Comment: Those commands work with my module. But It seems that I can't receive an IP:
My output now is: 
AT+SAPBR=2,1

+SAPBR: 1,3,"0.0.0.0"

OK
AT+HTTPINIT

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL"," http://www.google.com"

OK
AT+HTTPACTION=0

OK

+HTTPACTION: 0,601,0

I've used #define APN "everywhere"
#define USER "eesecure"
#define PWD "secure"
My provider is Orange -> https://www.teamknowhow.com/discover/discover/orange-apn-settings

Comment: The sim800L is not capable of making HTTPS requests to my knowledge (at least I could only get mine to work with HTTP ) . 601 errors, if I remember correctly, are the result of trying to call an HTTPS domain. Try the same commands with a domain that you know is HTTP.

Comment: ok - I've added the sequence of commands I had to use to get mine to work in making an HTTP request. Make sure you use an HTTP endpoint, and not HTTPS. Does it work?

Comment: One final point: I don't trust the page - https://www.teamknowhow.com/discover/discover/orange-apn-settings - I didn't get my Orange card to work with those settings. It's far better to put the sim card in your phone and see what settings are auto-generated following setup. Then copy these.

Comment: My phone say that the APN is "net" with no user and pwd

Comment: "My phone say that the APN is "net" with no user and pwd " - that sounds correct - I set up mine in Luxembourg just using orange.lu as the APN, with user and password blank. I'm not sure what it would be in your territory.

Comment: NB - It's definitely an APN issue because your +SAPBR: 1,3,"0.0.0.0" return string should contain an IP address and not 0s

Comment: Yep. I moved to just "net" and now I have an IP. I can't send req to https, but this is not a problem, if I send to a http url I get AT+HTTPACTION=0. Should I assume that the get request worked?

Comment: Great! You can also print the content of the request some how (though I can't remember right now how to do it) - To confirm it works it's often best to check server side that it has made the correct call. AT+HTTPACTION=0 is the correct response, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of send commands to set up TCP/IP connection:

```
//Check the registration status
AT+CREG?

//Check attach status
AT+CGACT?

//Attach to the network
AT+CGATT=1

//Wait for Attach
WAIT=7

//Start task ans set the APN. Check your carrier APN
AT+CSTT="bluevia.movistar.es" // Here you havve net which I guess is not a NetworkAPN you have to use the APN from your provider (= sim card)

//Bring up the wireless connection
AT+CIICR

//Wait for bringup
WAIT=6

//Get the local IP address
AT+CIFSR

//Start a TCP connection to remote address. Port 80 is TCP.
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","74.124.194.252","80"

//Set prompt of '>' when module sends data
AT+CIPSPRT=1

//Send the TCP data
AT+CIPSEND
```

If you want to test quickly a stable setup use this [7 days free to use tool for SIM800, SIM900](https://www.m2msupport.net/m2msupport/wp-content/themes/admired/download_sm_package.php) and then copy the succesfull process into code.

Comment: My antivirus detects a Trojan in the arhive and automaticaly deltes it. I've tried to download the tool too

Comment: I have it there is no trojan in it (I guess its a false positive) Get a better Anti virus ;-) I tested with Avast latest version.